# Can any ambiguous context-free grammar be converted into Chomsky normal form?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, normal-forms

Can an ambiguous context-free grammar be converted into Chomsky normal form? I think the answer is yes.

Comment: Please improve the title of your post. It is too broad.

Comment: @ice1000 It's usually useful for a question such as this one to include the asker's thoughts on what the answer is and what they did to try to answer it themself.

Answer (score 3):

Any context free grammar can be converted into the equivalent [Chomsky Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form). It does not matter if it is ambiguous or not.